# What is the view of List.sublist(n,m)?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, classcastexception

I'm trying to cut an `ArrayList<String>` in 2 halves.

```
ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<>(), out1, out2;
out1 = (ArrayList<String>) in.subList(0,2); //will cause an ClassCastException: List cannot be casted to ArrayList
out2 = (ArrayList<String>) in.subList(2,5); // either here
```

Why? what is the view representing, which subList returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList`'s `subList` method returns an instance of an inner class of `ArrayList` called `SubList` (`private class SubList extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess`), not an `ArrayList`. You can store it in a `List` variable, but you can't cast it to an `ArrayList`.

If you want your sub list to be an independant ArrayList, you can create a new ArrayList :

```
out1 = new ArrayList<String> (in.subList(0,2)); 
out2 = new ArrayList<String> (in.subList(2,5));
```

Comment: so it is no ArrayList neither a Linked List? how it the sublist represented in memory?

Comment: @Joel It is backed by the original ArrayList.

Comment: why is not just a instance of arrayList? - whats the benefit of not returning the orignial type?

Comment: @Joel It returns a List Object.

Comment: @Joel The idea is that it doesn't create new storage for a new ArrayList, which is useful if the original ArrayList is large and you need a large subList of it. Instead of copying all the elements to a new List, it holds a reference to the original List. For example, get(i) is implemented as `return ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);` (i.e. it gets the element from the original ArrayList)

Comment: It’s not only avoiding copying, it is the intended idiom for certain list manipulations, e.g. to remove all items in the index range `(4, 10)`, use `list.subList(4, 10).clear();` which is concise and more efficient than calling `remove()` multiple times. You may also combine sublists with [`fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill-java.util.List-T-), [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#replaceAll-java.util.List-T-T-), `copy`, `rotate`, `reverse`, `sort`, etc.